# Scons in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ssl, scons

When i run scons --ssl all, it throws an error:

> g++ -o build/linux2/release/ssl/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.o -c
>   -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -pipe -fno-builtin-memcmp -O3 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -D_SCONS -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DSUPPORT_UTF8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DMONGO_SSL -DMONGO_HAVE_HEADER_UNISTD_H -DMONGO_HAVE_EXECINFO_BACKTRACE -DNETSNMP_NO_INLINE -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/libstemmer_c/include -Isrc/third_party/libstemmer_c/include -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/s2 -Isrc/third_party/s2 -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/boost -Isrc/third_party/boost -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/pcre-8.30 -Isrc/third_party/pcre-8.30 -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl -Isrc -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/mongo -Isrc/mongo -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/s2 -Isrc/third_party/s2 -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/snappy -Isrc/third_party/snappy -Ibuild/linux2/release/ssl/third_party/v8/include -Isrc/third_party/v8/include src/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.cpp
>
> src/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.cpp: In member function 'void
>   mongo::SSLManager::_setupFIPS()':
>   src/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.cpp:187: error: 'FIPS_mode_set' was not
>   declared in this scope scons: ***
>   [build/linux2/release/ssl/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.o] Error 1 scons:
>   building terminated because of errors.

How to fix this issue. Using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

To address this error make sure that you have a version of OpenSSL installed that defines FIPS_mode_set. Some versions of 0.9.8 for example don't. Upgrading to 1.0.1 should address.

If you are already on 1.0.1 make sure that correct OpenSSL headers and libraries are being used by scons. You can set explicitly by adding the include and lib paths as a command line arguments, as follows:

```
scons --ssl --cpppath /usr/local/openssl/1.0.1e/include --libpath /usr/local/openssl/1.0.1e/lib all
```

Where the paths provided are the actual paths of your OpenSSL include and libraries.

Comment: how to check whether correct OpenSSL headers are being used by scons?? and please guide me how to set explicitly

Comment: I have updated my answer above with an example. I added --libpath as well which may be required as well.

Comment: @JamesWahlin - could you add this info (about setting the paths) to the MongoDB docs for building mongo (http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/)? I actually filed a bug in the MongoDB JIRA b/c the "build on linux" tutorial has a link to "Edit on github", but that link is broken. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-2173

Comment: If this is the answer, can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same issue with OSX on Mac. Here is what you need to include:

```
scons --ssl --cpppath=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --libpath=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib all
```

assuming you've downloaded openssl with brew

```
brew install openssl
```